# $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{15+2x-x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{15+2x-x^2}}$$
I tried:

$\int \frac{dx}{-\sqrt{x^2-2x-15}}$$ = $$-\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2-16}}$

now I tried both: $x-1=4\sec t$  and $x-1=4 \cos t$  answer of both was complicated( contain $ln$ and $sqrt$....)
I wonder is there another way to solve this integral?

Comment: You are doing something peculiar with your minus signs. I get $$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{4^2-(x-1)^2}}$$ which suggests the substitution $x-1=4\sin t$.

Comment: $-\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{1-x}{4}\right)$

Comment: ok the point is: it is harder to solve $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}$$
 but easier to solve $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$$  true?

Comment: yes because the trig sub is different in each situation

Comment: @Soheil0098 None of these is difficult to solve since it is well-known that $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}=\ln |x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}|+C$ and $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+C$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the the called Eulersubstitution:
$$\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}=xt+\sqrt{c}$$ for $c>0$ in your case
$$\sqrt{-x^2+2x+15}=xt+\sqrt{15}$$
$$x=\frac{2-2t\sqrt{15}}{t^2+1}$$
$$dx=-2/15\,{\frac {\sqrt {15} \left( 5\,t+\sqrt {15} \right)  \left( -3\,t
+\sqrt {15} \right) }{ \left( {t}^{2}+1 \right) ^{2}}}
dt$$

Comment: This is an overkill for this integral.

Answer (score 1):

First complete the square to form

$$-x^2 + 2x+ 15 =4^2-(x-1)^2$$
then rewrite the problem as

$$I =\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{15+2x-x^2}}=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{4^2-(x-1)^2}}$$

now substitute $u = x-1$. Then $du =dx$ and

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{4^2-(x-1)^2}}=\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{4^2-u^2}}$$

which we can substitute $u=4\sin t$ , $du=4\cos t \,dt$ to produce

$$\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{4^2-u^2}}=\int \frac{4\cos t \,dt}{\sqrt{4^2-4^2\sin^2 t}}=\int \frac{4\cos t \,dt}{4\sqrt{\cos^2(t)}}=\int dt = t + C$$

where

$$u=4\sin t \implies t=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac u4\right)$$

and

$$u=x-1 \implies t=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac {x-1}4\right)$$

so that

$$ I = t + C = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac {x-1}4\right) + C$$